# When is the usual time to apply for the Gaming Promotional Grant?

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

So I was waiting for round 9 and didn't happen to come on here for two days, only to find I already missed it!

How long are the grant applications usually open for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, grants are open until the following Sunday or Monday. This grant opened late, however, but because of release times I didn't shift the closing date.

I had extended the deadline to a couple hours after this was posted. That has passed now, but we got some new applicants in the mean time! Now calculating the new recipients.

Comment: I didn't expect you to do this, I was just curious as to the opening times. This will make me lurk more on the weekends I guess ;) A big thank you for re-opening the application!