# How can we improve our traction on Facebook, etc.?

Tags: discussion

Currently our [Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/GamingStackExchange/154617661300474) is pretty pitiful, a handful of likes, and almost no interaction. I think we should take a look at how we use the page, what we're trying to acheive with it, and how we can improve the 'traction' (likes, interactions, views) of the page.

Comment: Simple, GnomeSlice needs to post more actively!

Comment: [A good article](http://blog.usabilla.com/ux-facebook-pages/) came up on Hacker News recently. Not all the tips are relevant, but a lot of it is.

Answer (score 11):

- **The purpose of the page** is to make people aware of Gaming.SE. Currently, there's a vast number of avid gamers who have no idea the site exists. To within an acceptable margin of error, all these people are on Facebook.
- **We should be using the page** to post the best/most interesting content from the site (as we do), as well as advertising our servers (as we do) and promotional grants (we currently don't). Even though new people we reach won't have the necessary rep to participate, free copies of new games are a pretty big incentive to get people actually involved in the site. It's also a way to get [conveniently notified](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/gaming-promotional-grant-time-open-to-apply) when they do happen. Above all the content we post should be highly *shareable*, i.e. fall into one of the well-defined categories of internet amusement value (omg,wtf,lol etc.). Why aren't any of our amusingly title questions up there already?
- **We can improve traction by:**

  - As well as advertising promotional grants, increase the amount of content. A post is visible on Facebook momentarily when it's posted, one post a week is not enough.
  - Encouraging community participation. A simply way to do this would be to allow users who suggest content for the Facebook page to have it submitted using their sharing url, thereby increasing their chances of winning Announcer, Booster etc.
  - Embedding @Gaming mentions into all posts shared using the share buttons on questions (*is this possible?*).

**EDIT**

We should hook up the blog to Facebook, so that blog posts are automatically posted to our page.

Comment: I mentoined the promotional grant to 2 friends. One immediately decided to join, the other alerted a friend who he knew would love the site.

Comment: I posted about it on Facebook, it received quite a bit of attention.

Comment: So far, the facebook page contains a promotional ad for the Battlefield 3 server, and I did post about the newest round of the gaming grant a few days ago as well.

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply, our Facebook page doesn't post much.  I think this would be (at least partially) alleviated if it had more admins.  GnomeSlice posted a screenshot on the bridge once, and I was able to see that only him and one other person were admins (now that might have changed, and IMHO should, but I would think we would've heard about it).

Comment: Currently, I, Wipqozn, Mana, and @DavidFullerton are the admins.  That can be subject to change though.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be ideal for us to post at least one **good** answer per day on the page.  I know I started the page, but I'm not really up on the popular games of the day, so the other page administrators will have to help me out.

One idea that came to me, was to create a chatroom for the facebook page, where we could discuss what we want to post for that day.

Thoughts?

Comment: That chatroom idea sounds good

Answer (score 3):

Make "Hot Questions" (the question RSS feed) more prominent by putting it on the wall, perhaps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work like that.  I could make it the default landing screen for users coming to the page, but it still won't show up in people's news feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Have the Twitter bot also post the same questions on Facebook, Google+, MySpace and whatever other social networks allow automated postings.

Comment: MySpace? Lol...

Comment: @fredley I know, but it was the only one I could think of that had some kind app API.

Comment: This is already in place on the facebook page, but as far as I know, there's no way to make it post to the page as 'wall posts' which are what show up in users' news feeds.